# Interrupted Error in MySQL Workbench Query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
alter table `market_market_types` 
add constraint `market_market_types_market_id_foreign` 
foreign key (`market_id`) references `market` (`id`) 
on delete cascade;
```

While trying to run the query above in mysql workbench I get an error that says query interrupted and no errors are displayed
My view configurations are as follows

[image]

Comment: Please do not use any tags that have nothing to do with the question. There is no association with Laravel, so please remove the tag.

Answer (score 4):

you should check first if the output area height is actually visible (drag the bottom of the main view if not)

The most probable issue should be that there is no default database selected: just double clic on desired one.